# Admob adview steals focus from keyboard

Tags: android, admob, android-softkeyboard, adview

I am creating remote mouse and keyboard app where you can write on your PC remotely.

I show keyboard and receive keyboard keystrokes using activity onKeyDown() method.

I have admob ad in top of screen. The issue I face that onKeyDown() method of activity is not called unless I remove admob adview.

I tried remove focus from ad view . I tried hiding adview when keyboard is shown. nothing fixed my issue. Please advise.[image]

Answer (score 1):

OnKeyDown is only for hardware keyboards.  Software keyboard usually do not send onKeyxxx events.  You need to set up an InputConnection and implement that interface, particularly commitText.  Interacting with software keyboards directly is actually a lot of work.

Comment: I don't agree with you. When i remove ad, on key down is called from software keyboard

Comment: I wrote software keyboards for 4 years.  There may be some keyboard out there that does it, if you put it into null mode.  Most will not.